# Silently play and stop audio file with FFPlay

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

So I'm building a simple alarm clock application and I'm using FFPlay to play the alarm sound. I'd like to play the sound 'silently' (no console output or windows pop ups) but when I do I can't stop FFPlay without killing the process.

Command:

```
ffplay -i "C:\Users\GJBalaich\Google Drive\Audition\Run Alarm\Exports\Run Alarm.mp3" -loop 0 -showmode 0 -loglevel -8 -exitonkeydown
```

So it's just looping an audio file, and I have `-showmode` set to 0 which is video so there is no pop up window (since there is no video stream). However, I've found that `-exitonkeydown` doesn't actually work unless you're focused on the FFPlay pop-up window, which I disabled.

Is there any way to stop FFPlay gracefully without focusing on the pop-up window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keypress events are intercepted by SDL which is what draws the display window. So, no window equals no key events.

On Windows, to terminate ffplay remotely, run

```
taskkill /f /im ffplay.exe
```

assuming you have only one ffplay running. If not, get the PID for the relevant ffplay via

```
tasklist | findstr ffplay
```

and then

```
taskkill /f /pid XYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

`ffplay` has an option to "auto exit" when it is done playing the audio or video file:

```
ffplay --autoexit /your/media/file.ogg
```